# Singular and plural nouns in one sentence

Tags: grammatical-number

"They qualify for government-supported medical *treatment* and disability *payments*."

In the sentence above, why is the word "treatment" used as a singular noun, and "payments" as a plural noun? I guess there could be several different forms of disability payments, so using *-s* after *payment* seems ok, but why not treatment"s"?

Can't there also be many different kinds of medical treatments that the government supports?
Or is the word *treatment* mostly used as an uncountable noun?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "treatment" is used in its uncountable aspect because the writer is concerned with treatment in general in this particular sentence; of course, it is quite possible that several sorts of treatment are available and if the discussion comes to the point of giving information about a given one, then the indefinite article "a/an" can still be used and you can also speak of that particular treatment as treatment in general. In the case of the plural of "payment" I think that there is no question at all of a variety of payments but simply a reference to the fact that payment is made on the basis of eligibility and therefore must be monthly or weekly, which entails that each small monthly or weekly allowance is a payment, thereby, speaking of all of them together, the need to use a plural.

Comment: ... And non-count usages of nouns are almost always singular in form, and thus confusable with singular usages. '_One treatment that has worked well, unlike several earlier ones, is ...'._ And 'payment' as well as 'treatment' has both non-count and count usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is that saying that "beers" is a non-count usage that is exceptionally plural (cans of beers, sorts of beer)?

Comment: No. "We have a range of beers" uses a count usage. As is "Three beers, please." // A plural-form non-count usage is: "Thee house's surroundings were incredible." Plural in form, plural agreement ... _but you can't have 2 / 17 / a dozen / several surroundings_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Those have the label "[pl]" (plural) in the OALD, a label that doesn't tell the whole story, that can be misleading. They are not quite plural. thanks for the precision; I found the formulation awkward, given the only meaning I could find for it at first. It's all clear now.

Comment: 'Thee' of course is a good old-fashioned typo.